# Height increase to Top direction

Tags: html, css

I have an element "**.ntf-container**" and I insert some sub-elements **.ntf-card**'s

When I insert the elements, the "container" increases toward the Bottom, but the list is at the bottom, it needs to increase towards the top, to show the notifications.

Like facebook notifications.

Comment: Could you provide some more information: samples of your code, a diagram of what you want it to look like, and what you've tried so far. That'll help, because right now I can't really provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using flexbox for this container, you can do something clever:

```
.ntf-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

This will put the last items on the top of the container, and the first items at the bottom of the container.

[flex-direction rule on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)